# How merge three DataFrame in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, merge

How merge 3 DataFrame in Spark-Scala? I completly don't have any Idea how I can make this. On stackOverFlow I can't found similar example.

I have 3 similar DataFrames. The same name of Column, and the same number of them. Difference is only a value on rows.

#### DataFrame1:

```
+----+------+----+---+
|type| Model|Name|ID |
+----+------+----+---+
|  1 |wdasd |xyzd|111|
|  1 |wd    |zdfd|112|
|  1 |bdp   |2gfs|113|
+----+------+----+---+
```

#### DataFrame2:

```
+----+------+----+---+
|type| Model|Name|ID |
+----+------+----+---+
|  2 |wdasd |xyzd|221|
|  2 |wd    |zdfd|222|
|  2 |bdp   |2gfs|223|
+----+------+----+---+
```

#### DataFrame3:

```
+----+------+----+---+
|type| Model|Name|ID |
+----+------+----+---+
|  3 |AAAA  |N_AM|331|
|  3 |BBBB  |NA_M|332|
|  3 |CCCC  |MA_N|333|
+----+------+----+---+
```

And I want to this type of DataFrame

#### MergeDataFrame:

```
+----+------+----+---+
|type| Model|Name|ID |
+----+------+----+---+
|  1 |wdasd |xyzd|111|
|  1 |wd    |zdfd|112|
|  1 |bdp   |2gfs|113|
|  2 |wdasd |xyzd|221|
|  2 |wd    |zdfd|222|
|  2 |bdp   |2gfs|223|
|  3 |AAAA  |N_AM|331|
|  3 |BBBB  |NA_M|332|
|  3 |CCCC  |MA_N|333|
+----+------+----+---+
```

Comment: use union function as `df1.union(df2).union(df3)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine(concatenate) two data frames with the same column name in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397206/how-can-i-combineconcatenate-two-data-frames-with-the-same-column-name-in-java)

Comment: Also, this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332434/concatenate-two-pyspark-dataframes

Comment: and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554601/efficiently-using-union-in-spark

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spark provides a `union` and `unionAll`. Looks like they are deprecating the `unionAll` function so I would use the `union` function as below:

```
dataFrame1.union(dataFrame2).union(dataFrame3)
```

Note that in order to union data frames the data frames must have the exact same column names in the exact same order.

See the spark docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)